# Chart js each label for each data

Tags: laravel, chart.js

***how to add label for each item in chart js instead of one label for all data***

```
    labels: ['Most Bought Assets', 'Most Bought Consumable','# of Item in A', '# of Item in B', '# of Good(Assets)],
    datasets: [{

           label:["January,February,March,April,May"],

        data: [5,4,3,2,1],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],

    }]
```

**instead of like this**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your labels currently are one long string, I suppose this has to be an array of strings:

```
label: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May"],
```